What was the nature of Moroni after he died as a human being, did he become an angel?
In this short background information of The Book of Mormon, we learn that Moroni was the son of the American prophet Mormon, who must have died as a human being.
But then the article said:

Latter-day Saints believe that it was to this hillside, today called the Hill Cumorah, near Palmyra, New York, that Moroni returned in 1823 as an angel to lead the teenage boy Joseph Smith to the hidden plates. Joseph Smith later founded The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints.

In mainstream Christianity, a human being will be given a glorified body after the general resurrection, retaining his/her bodily nature, never becoming an angel who is always 100% spirit.  Before general resurrection, for denominations that believe in the conscious intermediate state, the souls of those who passed away would NOT have a body and God would not have permitted these body-less souls to appear to the living.  God would have sent an angel instead who has always been spiritual, only that God would give this angel a temporary bodily appearance so humans can see this angel.
How does human being Moroni re-appearing as an angel explained by LDS in light of the normal progression of the human being's journey after death?

Was Moroni's human nature changed into an angel?
Was the term "angel" to describe Moroni not precise, i.e. it was Moroni in his glorified body (like Jesus after resurrection) appearing to Joseph Smith as like an angel?
Or was it a special act of God that Moroni's consciousness (which God maintains prior to his eventual resurrection along with everyone else) was given a temporary angelic nature for the purpose of his mission in 1823? That once that mission was completed God change him back into a non-resurrected human being after his mission?

Pardon my ignorance:

I know very little of the LDS "anthropology" of post-mortem nature of human being and of how LDS understand the angelic nature.  For example, do we become angels?  What IS an angel; is an angel 100% spiritual like what mainstream Christianity teaches?

And I don't know the "standard timeline" either (i.e. whether a human being is resurrected right after dying rather than waiting along with the rest of humanity).


My question is primarily about whether the Moroni's case is unique or typical when compared to the normal progression of a human being's life after death.

does https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/34425/22319 answer most of this?

@depperm I read the dictionary article on Angels, and yes, it helps a lot with my question.  It would be nice for an answer to apply that article to the case of Moroni's appearance specifically.  For example, the answer can confirm my understanding that God re-embodied Moroni for the ministry but the embodiment is no longer (because ministry was completed), thus he is waiting along with all of us who have passed (including Moses, Elijah, John the Baptist) for future exaltation and celestial glory.

This question is not an exact duplicate, but it's a strict subset of the broader question of "what is the church's doctrine about the nature of angels and their relationship to humankind?" that is answered in the other question.  Moroni is not considered by the church to be "a special case" in this regard.

@MasonWheeler Thanks for the input.  I'm fine with this question being marked as "duplicate" then.

The introduction at the front of the Book of Mormon provides this relevant detail: "… the same Moroni, then a glorified, resurrected being, appeared to the Prophet Joseph Smith …" (https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bofm/introduction?lang=eng). That puts the answer closest to option 2 (of your 3 options). The introduction is in the category of "study helps" – revised periodically, not part of the canonized text, useful and generally reliable, but not definitive. It would be interesting to know what sources were drawn from when the introduction was written.

@SamuelBradshaw So in LDS, there are some human beings who have received glorified bodies before "general resurrection"?  Or perhaps there is no such thing as a future event "general resurrection" for all souls who have died?  If so, what's special about Moroni?  In Catholicism, only Jesus and Marry received their glorified bodies.

@GratefulDisciple The general resurrection is just that: general.  It does not preclude other people being resurrected at other times.  Remember that the Bible says that shortly after Jesus' resurrection, many good people who had been dead were resurrected as well.  There are also a lot of apocryphal works about the early Apostolic Period containing scenes where some skeptical person would ask "how should we believe that people can be raised from the dead?" and one of the Apostles would say "like this," and command some random dead person to rise up again.

These works are apocryphal, not canonical, for a reason, but the stories are common enough to establish that, at the very least, there were a lot of early Christians who believed this was a real thing that their leaders were actually doing.
